# Show message after submit the form.

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

This is not working for the way I would like it to work. It prints out the message at the bottom of my body element, below form. Message should be printed inside the form element, below submit button.

PHP code

```
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
                echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
            } else {
                echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
            }
```

HTML

```
<form>
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="submit"></label>
    <div class="controls">
     <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I tried to give a class to echo paragraph, but all it does is add another paragraph below the form. This is happening on the same php page.

Comment: Move the phpcode top of your page, and add variable `$Message='<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';` and after the submit button `<?php echo $Message;?>`

Comment: Put your php code where you need the message to be shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to explain that `echo` is merely an `output` of content.
There is no difference for example between:

```
<?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>
```

and

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Now when you take this into consideration, you will see that every single output is printed to the browser in the order they were executed.

So to put it simply, the echo of the message needs to occur in the place it is intended to be written, i.e. inside the form opposed to below it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <form>
 <div class="control-group">
 <label class="control-label" for="submit"></label>
  <div class="controls">
  <button>Submit</button>     
  <?php 
  // if you want it here 
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
            echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
        } else {
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
        }
     ?>
  </div>
 </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: i would go for this way, cause if you make the action in another file, the message will print below content because it doesnt have position in html, you could also make the php to print the whole html again and then you could echo the message where you want it to echo